# How to authenticate users on TortoiseHg web server?

Tags: authentication, mercurial, dvcs, tortoisehg

TortoiseHg web server configuration has an "Allow Push" parameter where I put the users allowed to push changes. But when I try to push I get an "authorization failed" error. How are the users authenticated? Where do the passwords come from?

Answer (score 8):

Setting `allow_push = *` will allow anybody to push to your repository served with `hg serve`. You should of course only do that on a trusted network. Apart from that, you cannot do authentication with `hg serve` -- you need a webserver in front of it that will authenticate users.

Please see [hgrc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#web) for a terse explanation of `allow_push` and the [wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) for a slightly longer explanation about what `hg serve` is for.

Comment: Thanks for answering Martin.
They say:
"...the authenticated user name must be present in this list (separated by whitespace or ,)"
So do I have to put the user authenticated by the web server? I tried to put the user authenticated by Windows with no success.

Comment: Yes, you list the user authenticated by the webserver. Mercurial knows nothing about Windows: it only looks in the standard `REMOTE_USER` environment variable set by the webserver before the CGI script is envoked.

Comment: @MartinGeisler Can you explain how you would use REMOTE_USER to add users to the `hg server` webserver? If it isn't able to use that parameter why did they have it? Or does it only work if you have some other server integrated in with Hg?

Comment: @ArtB you cannot "add users to `hg serve`" with the environment variable. What I said was that Mercurial doesn't do authentication — it only does authorization. Use a frontend webserver like Nginx or Apache if you need authentication.

Comment: Thank you, I was confused. From the [wiki link](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Choosing_a_publishing_method) it does seem like that property only works if you integrate it with a real webserver only.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just getting into Mercurial, and from what I can tell (and read in the documentation), the TortoiseHg web server isn't meant to be a permanent solution. The docs seem to steer you towards running either Apache or lighttpd.

You may also want to check out [Vampire Basic's tutorial on running Mercurial on Windows](http://vampirebasic.blogspot.com/2009/06/running-mercurial-on-windows.html).

Comment: Since posting this I've gone through the tutorial linked to and am now successfully hosting Hudson via WinXP/IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just edit your hgrc file, under the [authorize] section:
[Store password in TortoiseHg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997601/store-password-in-tortoisehg/1998637)