# How do I get TortoiseHG to remember my password?

Tags: passwords, tortoisehg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Store password in TortoiseHg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997601/store-password-in-tortoisehg)

Seems simple enough. When doing a sync, I tire of entering my password for each sync, each repo. I seem to recall knowing how to do it somewhere once upon a time, but shy of going in and updating EACH project's syncing URLs, is there another method? That'll be tedious, so I'm somewhat loathe to goto each project and update each one.

Thoughts?

Comment: Just when I thought I was making the right choice on the community to post my question to, *bam* off to SO it goes ;)

Comment: And *bam* closed as exact dupe!  Answer at dupe, btw.

Comment: @Will ~ thanks, wasn't sure if I should ask for it to be closed on those grounds, but once it got moved here I saw that it was indeed an exact dupe. Thanks for closing, don't mind it in the least. :D