# automatically fill password in batch

Tags: batch-file

I would like to log in automatically to tortoise hg but I don't know how to achieve it:(

I have below command:

```
@echo off
hg clone https://name@bitbucket.org/myproj -r myBranch
hg pull
```

when I execute this script it ask me to type the password but i would like to fill in automatically :( 
i tried to use:

```
hg clone https://name@bitbucket.org/myproj -r myBranch -p mypass
```

but it failed :(

Any advice will be gratefull :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is in [Store password in TortoiseHg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1997611/4019425) on Stackoverflow

Try https://myBranch:mypass@bitbucket.org/myproj

Comment: lol....that was the gist :)
too be honest with you I saw this page and this post erlier but I didn't take any resonable conclusion...After when you  put a link to it again it enlighten me :) THANKS