# Pulling into bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, tortoisehg-2.0

I'm using TortoiseHG (Mercurial).

I can commit my project to a local repository, but I cannot push my project to bitbucket. When I push my project, the system is starting push, but this action will have not finished. I have such screen:

[image: THG Main Screen]

Next, I tried to recreate the repository on my hardDrive in the following way:  I copied `.hg` to another directory and push again. But I have the same problem.

I tried to recreate free repo on my bitbucket and after it I push my repo to cloud. But I still see the same problem.

Comment: I cannot post an image. I have not enough reputation.

Comment: Login/Password wrong? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8197696

Comment: `push` is the right command, not pull. Can you *push* to another local repository which you created by *clone* (and not simply copying the folder)?

Comment: I'm going to try it now.

Comment: Why did my question minus?

Comment: @planetmaker - it's **pushing** operation (see screenshot), which failed. *Full*  local clone will be not pushable, obviously

Comment: I suppose, -1 is "no homework done" result

Comment: @planetmaker Yes, I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Enable debug output (Synchronize 1 - Options 2 - Emit debugging output 3)
   [image: Sync Options]
2. Try "Outgoing" button from toolbar (3-rd) instead of push - THG must detect pushable changesets and show set if all good in repository (you have some "draft" /pushable/ changesets in history - 45:, THG stuck on "search for changes" stage)
3. Check your local repo with `hg verify`
4. Use fresh TortoiseHG (3.5)

PS - local clones of repo **must be** created only with `hg clone`, not by copying (possibly broken) .hg dir

Comment: I recreated new repository without history.