# TortoiseHg / Mercurial 3.6.2 x64 not remembering credentials

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-keyring

I recently upgraded to TortoiseHg 3.6.2 x64 and since then the mercurial_keyring setting does not work. I had previously followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997601/store-password-in-tortoisehg) (the ones that show how to enable mercurial_keyring extension). Here's what I have:

**Mercurial.ini**

```
[extensions]
mercurial_keyring =
```

**Local Repo .hg\hgrc**

```
[paths]
http://username@repo.url/repo.hg
```

Now, ever time I try to pull/push etc from TortoiseHg, I am asked for my username and password. When I disable mercurial_keyring, then I am just asked for my password.

If I downgrade to TortoiseHg 3.5.2 x64 then it works again.

Any ideas please? Is there a minimum compatible server-side Mercurial version for this to work with TortoiseHg 3.6.2? I think we are running 2.7.1 on the server under Linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a change in behaviour caused by TortoiseHg 3.6.2. It looks to me like a bug, although as of yet is unconfirmed if it was an intentional change or not.

The relevant mercurial_keyring issue is [here](https://bitbucket.org/Mekk/mercurial_keyring/issues/49/mercurial_keyring-always-asks-for-user). The only reason I wonder if it's intentional or not is that the current docs state:

> Simpler form with url-embedded name can also be used:
>
> `[paths] bitbucket = https://John@my.server.com/hgrepo/someproject/`
>
> **but is not recommended.**

The workaround appears to be to specify the username outside of the URL.

```
[paths]
myremote = https://my.server.com/hgrepo/someproject

[auth]
myremote.prefix = https://my.server.com/hgrepo
myremote.username = John
```

Comment: Thanks Chris - I'll give the workaround a try and report back.